# Form validation text error - text disappears

Tags: jquery, html, forms

An example of a basic form...it is working but the error text "cannot be blank" disappears after appearing for a second

```
    <html>
    <head><title>Form</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <form>
    Enter EmailID:
    <input type="text" name="email"><br>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
    </form>
    <span></span>
    <script src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
     $("input[name=submit]").click(function(){
     if(!$("input[name=email]").val())
      {
          $("<span>Cannot be Blank</span>").appendTo("span");
      }
     });
    });
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you want to prevent the default behaviour use [`.preventDefault()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/). For example in your case a form submit event, if you want to validate inputs before form post use event.preventDefault().

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $("input[name=submit]").click(function(e){
     if(!$("input[name=email]").val())
      {
          e.preventDefault();
          $("<span>Cannot be Blank</span>").appendTo("span");
      }
     });
});
```